# Any way to disable or get around checkNameAndValue exceptions on OkHttp?

Tags: okhttp

I'm trying to make a call with OkHttp and I'm getting an exception because one of the headers has an issue. The header is:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="O Último Caçador de Bruxas (2016) 5.1 CH Dublado 1080p.mp4"`

I have no control over the server so I want to know if I can tell OkHttp to ignore that error?

Here is the full exception.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0xda at 24 in content-disposition value: attachment; filename="O Último Caçador de Bruxas (2016) 5.1 CH Dublado 1080p.mp4"
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.checkNameAndValue(Headers.java:283)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.add(Headers.java:233)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.internal.http.Http2xStream.readHttp2HeadersList(Http2xStream.java:263)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.internal.http.Http2xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http2xStream.java:149)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:723)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:81)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:708)
                                                                                                                                  at com.facebook.stetho.okhttp3.StethoInterceptor.intercept(StethoInterceptor.java:59)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:681)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:563)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:241)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
                                                                                                                                  at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in OkHttp. You can workaround it by disabling HTTP/2.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#protocols-java.util.List-

Comment: Had to remove `SPDY_3` as well. Thanks.